# Why use wrappers around the actual iterator functions in LINQ extension methods?

Tags: c#, linq, iterator

When looking at Microsoft's implementation of various C# LINQ methods, I noticed that the public extension methods are mere wrappers that return the actual implementation in the form of a separate iterator function.

For example (from System.Linq.Enumerable.cs):

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Concat<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> first, IEnumerable<TSource> second) {
    if (first == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("first");
    if (second == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("second");
    return ConcatIterator<TSource>(first, second); 
}

static IEnumerable<TSource> ConcatIterator<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> first, IEnumerable<TSource> second) { 
    foreach (TSource element in first) yield return element;
    foreach (TSource element in second) yield return element; 
}
```

What is the reason for wrapping the iterator like that instead of combining them into one and return the iterator directly?

Like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Concat<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> first, IEnumerable<TSource> second) {
    if (first == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("first");
    if (second == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("second");
    foreach (TSource element in first) yield return element;
    foreach (TSource element in second) yield return element; 
}
```

Comment: Source https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,b4c65ba55f649b0e

Comment: Read this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#local-functions

Comment: @ivan Very interesting... Casually one of the features of C# 7.0 can be used to mitigate/evade a peculiarity of `yield`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wrappers are used to check method arguments immediately (i.e. when you call LINQ extension method). Otherwise arguments will not be checked until you start to consume iterator (i.e. use query in foreach loop or call some extension method which executes query - ToList, Count etc). This approach is used for all extension methods with deferred type of execution.

If you will use approach without wrapper then:

```
int[] first = { 1, 2, 3 };
int[] second = null;

var all = first.Concat(second); // note that query is not executed yet
// some other code
...
var name = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine($"Hello, {name}, we have {all.Count()} items!"); // boom! exception here
```

With argument-checking wrapper method you will get exception at `first.Concat(second)` line.

Comment: Very interesting... Didn't know that the state machine didn't start until you did a `GetEnumerator().MoveNext()`... Unclear why they did take this decision...

Comment: @xanatos in that case we wouldn't have deferred execution at all :)

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Yes, you are right... There is no way the compiler could distinguish between a "header" to be executed immediately and a "body" to be deferred. For a minute I thought "but it could run immediately and then stop just before the first yield", but then the execution (perhaps a query) would have already been done, only the return of the value would have been deferred :-)